# Using latitude,longitude of point and distance in degree to get another point?

Tags: latitude-longitude

Suppose I have latitude and longitude of a point and a distance in degree, how can I get to the other point? (Suppose the point to find is aligned horizontally or vertically)

Comment: Thanks for the question Ludovico. Can you include a lot more detail about your problem, software you are using, data that you have, if you are thinking of scripting something. Right now it is quite vague.

Comment: Do you want a distance, or the new point's coordinates, or what? If the "point to find is aligned horizontally or vertically", assuming horizontal and vertical are with respect to lines of lat/lon, you'd trivially add/subtract your degree distance from the appropriate lat or lon.

Comment: Geographiclib has a function named Direct that will calculate the xy point when you pass in lat,long,azimuth, distance.

Comment: Any distance in degrees on a sphere from a point defines a circle, not another point. For example, 90 degrees away from the north pole is the whole of the equator. If you have distance *and bearing or heading* (ie direction) then you can specify a point.

Comment: Distance in degrees is non-determinant -- one degree of latitude could be sixty nautical miles at the equator or zero at the poles. To work geodetic problems you need distance in a linear unit (e.g. meters) and bearing in an angular unit (e.g. degrees).

Comment: @vince I was thinking of distance in degrees subtended at the centre of the sphere - that's well defined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can do anything except treat the angular distance as if it's linear and do a 2D Cartesian calculation with it.